# Why can C# do this and C++/CLI cannot?

Tags: generics, delegates, c++-cli

.NET Framework 3.5 comes with all the LINQ goodies, and also includes predefined generic Func and Action delegates. They are generic for up to 4 arguments. I am writing a C++/CLI project that (unfortunately) uses VS 2005 and must only rely on the standard 2.0 assembly set (so no System.Core).

I tried defining my own generic delegates (in my own namespace) to make future ports easier, by the compiler chokes on this (multiple definitions). Any suggestions?

```
delegate void Action();

generic <typename Arg1>
delegate void Action(Arg1 arg1);
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: error C3756: 'Action': delegate definition conflicts with an existing symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here but I think your best bet is to define only those delegates in a C# assembly. C++/CLI has no problem making use of such a family of overloaded generics, but doesn't seem to be able to define them.